# Custom TabLayout in AlertDialog using ViewPager2

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am relatively new to writing apps and I am currently working at my second project. I have an activity called `AddNetwork`, which contains a button that should open an `AlertDialog`. In the `AlertDialog` I want to have a `TabLayout` with two tabs, that each show different content. I have been trying to achieve this for about 8 hours and I have found a few tutorials that partially cover my problem, but nothing that is really on point. I think I could solve my problem using `ViewPager2`, but I haven't managed to get it working yet. As of now my code works as follows:

`AddNetwork.java` creates an instance of `AlertDialogSelectWifi.java`, which extends `DialogFragment` and inflates the `alertdialog_select_wifi.XML` layout file that contains a `TabLayout`and a `ViewPager2`. Also in the `DialogFragment`, I am trying to set an adapter to the `viewPager`, namely `ViewPagerAdapter.java`, which extends `FragmentStateAdapter`. From there I would want to attach the two fragments `AlertDialogRecentFragment.java` (with `fragment_alert_dialog_recent.xml`) and `AlertDialogTypeFragment.java` (with `fragment_alert_dialog_type.xml`). Note that the latter is not yet included in the code, so as of now I would only add one fragment to the tabs (I guess).
So at the moment, my code is a somewhat chaotic mixture of all the tutorials I found and followed. It does not cause any errors and I am able to open the Alertdialog, however, the `fragment_alert_dialog_recent.xml` and the tabs are not visible.
I really don't know what else I could try or change in my code. Overall I am not sure whether it is correct to set the `ViewPagerAdapter` in the `AlertDialogSelectWifi.java` file or not. What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help is grealty appreciated!

Here is my code:

**AddNetwork.java**

```
public class AddNetwork extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_network);


        //BUTTON
        final MaterialButton buttonSelectWifi;
        buttonSelectWifi = (MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonSelectWifi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //CREATE ALERT DIALOG
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                DialogFragment dialog = AlertDialogSelectWifi.newInstance(context);
                dialog.show(fm, "dialog");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AlertDialogSelectWifi.java**

```
public class AlertDialogSelectWifi extends DialogFragment {

    static Context mContext;

    public static AlertDialogSelectWifi newInstance(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        return new AlertDialogSelectWifi();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);

        LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater(); //getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_select_wifi, null);

        builder.setTitle("Add Saved Network")
                .setView(alertLayout)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_select_wifi, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        ViewPager2 viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mContext, viewPager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
                new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                        tab.setText("Tab " + (position + 1));
                    }
                }).attach();
    }
}
```

**ViewPageAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager;

    public  ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, Context context, ViewPager2 viewPager) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return AlertDialogRecentFragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood your problem correctly change your adapter like this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

public  ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    if(position == 0)
    return new AlertDialogRecentFragment();
    else
    return new AlertDialogTypeFragment();
}

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the quick help! I implemented this, but unfortunately, the tabs and fragments still are not shown in the alert dialog. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share screenshot when fragmentdialog showed.

Comment: I added a screenshot. You can see (in light blue) the ```TabLayout```, but no tabs and no fragments are shown.

Comment: Remove onCreateDialog func.

Comment: ah yes that worked! now the tabs and fragments are shown! Thanks a lot! However, now the AlertDialog title and the cancel button are gone. Do you know if there is a way I can have both?

Comment: I think, you can add title and button to the xml file(alertdialog_select_wifi)

Comment: I'm gonna try that. Thank you for your help! You saved my day!